# How to get "review_summary" extension (premium data) of a place using google place API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

"Review_Summary" is an extension of Google place API which is used to get description of a place. 
This is the API:

I am trying to get description of a place using premium google place API:- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ74IAAFEEdkgRumQhfkGHklA&key=My_premium_key&extensions=review_summary

For example if we want to know about any place then we use this parameter like:- "Eiffel Tower" => The Eiffel Tower is a wrought iron lattice tower on the Champ de Mars in Paris, France. It is named after the engineer Gustave Eiffel, whose company designed and built the tower.

And While hitting this API with my key this is showing me access denied. This is the response.

```
{

    "html_attributions" : [],
    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Could anyone please help? Can I get this result of "review_ summary"? Any cost detail?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is help you. pass lat lng provide by google map

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=37.786971|-122.399677

Comment: this is use full to you?

Comment: you can not get place information using review_summary. you want to get Quick facts and this is provided by wikipedia api .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the extensions field were deprecated in 2017.

> Warning: The premium data (Zagat) feature is no longer supported after
>   May 2, 2017. Zagat ratings and reviews will no longer be available
>   from that point on. The search parameter zagatselected is no longer
>   accepted and the fields aspects , review_summary and zagat_selected
>   are no longer returned with search results.

as per https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=de (but not mentioned on the English page).

I'd very much like to see this info available again. It still shows up on Google Maps.